# Netherlands taxes

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I don't have any income except my salary and the taxes automatically deducted from it every month. Do I still need to declare my taxes every year ?

Comment: Have you read https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/living/everyday-essentials/finance/tax-time?

Comment: This question does not appear to have anything specific about being an ex-patriate.  It applies equally well to a Dutch citizen living in the Netherlands.  As such, I am afraid it is off-topic.

Comment: @MartinBonner: 1. It's a problem expatriates face. 2. Maybe the situation is different for expats w.r.t. reporting income.

Comment: @einpoklum "A problem expatriates face" is not sufficient to make it on-topic.  If the OP had overseas income, then it might well be on topic; however they only have salary.

Comment: Specifically "General questions about living in a country, which would similarly apply to a local citizen" are described in the help centre as off-topic.

Comment: @MartinBonner: 1. This is not a "general question". It's a very specific question. 2. OP doesn't know whether the question this applies similarly to a local citizen. By your criteria, we should remove half the questions in the [netherlands] tag.